# text() R-function - how to change the font of a single word?

Tags: r, fonts

```
text(x, y, font=2, "text")
```

changes the font of the whole 'text'.

But is it possible to change the font of a single word in 'text'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep!

```
plot.new()
text(0.5,0.5, expression(paste(bold("bold")," not bold")))
```

Take a look at `?plotmath` for a whole slew of other options and symbols that can be used.